# How to retain JMS Queue Message even after successful read?

Tags: queue, jms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using BPEL of Oracle Fusion Middleware 12C for my Project. The Requirement is to retain the message on queue even if it has been read by BPEL successfully.

i.e. as soon as Complete BPEL transaction is successful, Message gets removed from the queue. We can always reinsert the message in the queue but order of the messages changes.

Is there any configuration in weblogic which can help me achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMS - Going from one to multiple consumers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615744/jms-going-from-one-to-multiple-consumers). I think that answers your question.  You need a topic or multiple queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know ...there is NO configuration which can help you. All you can do is Either write some Java code OR Use Database Queue (AQ) to read the message without getting removed.

OR

If you are insisting using simple Distributed Queue then you can use 2 queue and move the message from one Queue to another queue which will also retain the message Order.

Comment: using 2 queues, you mean shift the messages from one to another while reading? Because I have another requirement in which I have to delete the particular message form the queue?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Via that way, you will be able to do much more than what can be done via one queue.